# How to generate signed url in Django Rest for a file in google cloud storage?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage

I am using Django Rest framework for making APIs. Along with it, I am using Google Cloud Storage to store media files. I have some questions in mind:

1. How do I generate signed file urls using the django rest framework? I have been searching the net with same but not able to get clear picture of it. [Link](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html)
2. So, if I delete a file in database, will it be automatically deleted from Google cloud storage as well?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I generate signed file urls using the django rest framework?

The [django-storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) module will take care of this for you automatically.

You can check it pretty easily, if you have uploaded an asset to your server, check the url at the FileField field of your model. (In my case it's called `raw`)

[image]

If you go to the right, you will see in the url the Signature parameter. If you reload the page, you'll see that the signature's value changes, proving you're actually using temporary signed urls.

Default expiration is 86400 seconds (1 day), you can [change](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html#settings) this with the `GS_EXPIRATION` variable.

> So, if I delete a file in database, will it be automatically deleted from Google cloud storage as well?

Not by default, but you can add this functionnality easily by [overriding](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) your Model's [delete method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects)

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to='filename/')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.myfile.delete()
        super(MyModel, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks @Overdrivr for the answer. Is there a way to get the url without exposing the folder structure?

Comment: The bucket names in google cloud and amazon s3 are global, anyone could find them so you not should rely on them for being private. That means the beginning of the url `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name` is a public resource (after all, you need to provide the path where the files are stored to your users). If you need to hide the folder name inside the bucket (which is `raws` in my case), you can simply put all files at the root of the bucket and use unique ID for each file.